# Change grunt (express) / protractor debug port

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, protractor

## Abstract

Hi, I've used `yeoman` with `angular-fullstack` in order to scaffold the initial configuration for my project. Unfortunatelly `angular-fullstack` doesn't contain a `protractor` package which I would like to use as my end-2-end test runner. So I've tried to connect protractor by myself.

## The problem

Though I've succeeded with connecting `protractor`, I've failed at making it work in `debug` mode. The problem is that both `protractor` and `express` get their debuggers launched on the same port `5858` and there is no way I've found that would allow changing those ports.

## The question

How do I make both `protractor` and `express` debuggers run on different custom ports?

## Additional info

Here's my Gruntfile.js, also I'll post additional info upon request:

```
// Generated on 2014-04-27 using generator-angular-fullstack 1.4.2
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        yeoman: {
            // configurable paths
            app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },
        express: {
            options: {
                debug: 5555,
                port: process.env.PORT || 9000
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    script: 'server.js',
                    debug: 7777
                }
            },
            prod: {
                options: {
                    script: 'dist/server.js',
                    node_env: 'production'
                }
            }
        },
        open: {
            server: {
                url: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            mochaTest: {
                files: ['test/server/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['env:test', 'mochaTest']
            },
            jsTest: {
                files: ['test/client/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            livereload: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/{,*//*}*.{html,jade}',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*//*}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*//*}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ],

                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            express: {
                files: [
                    'server.js',
                    'lib/**/*.{js,json}'
                ],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:server', 'express:dev', 'wait'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                    nospawn: true //Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
                }
            }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    jshintrc: 'lib/.jshintrc'
                },
                src: [ 'lib/{,*/}*.js']
            },
            all: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ],
            test: {
                options: {
                    jshintrc: 'test/client/.jshintrc'
                },
                src: ['test/client/spec/{,*/}*.js']
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dot: true,
                        src: [
                            '.tmp',
                            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*',
                            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/Procfile'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            heroku: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dot: true,
                        src: [
                            'heroku/*',
                            '!heroku/.git*',
                            '!heroku/Procfile'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                        src: '{,*/}*.css',
                        dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        // Debugging with node inspector
        'node-inspector': {
            custom: {
                options: {
                    'web-host': 'localhost'
                }
            }
        },

        // Use nodemon to run server in debug mode with an initial breakpoint
        nodemon: {
            debug: {
                script: 'server.js',
                options: {
                    nodeArgs: ['--debug-brk'],
                    env: {
                        PORT: process.env.PORT || 9000
                    },
                    callback: function (nodemon) {
                        nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
                            console.log(event.colour);
                        });

                        // opens browser on initial server start
                        nodemon.on('config:update', function () {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                require('open')('http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858');
                            }, 500);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        'bowerInstall': {
            app: {
                src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/index.html',
                html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/index.html',
                ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/styles/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/views/index.html',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/index.jade'],
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public'
            }
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/{,*/}*.html',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/{,*/}*.jade'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public']
            }
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            options: {
                cache: false
            },
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                        src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/images'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                        src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/images'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    //collapseWhitespace: true,
                    //collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    //removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    //removeOptionalTags: true
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views',
                        src: ['*.html', 'partials/**/*.html'],
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
        // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
        ngmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                        src: '*.js',
                        dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/*.html']
            }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        dot: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
                        src: [
                            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                            '.htaccess',
                            'bower_components/**/*',
                            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                            'fonts/**/*'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        dot: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views',
                        src: '**/*.jade'
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '.tmp/images',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/images',
                        src: ['generated/*']
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                        src: [
                            'package.json',
                            'server.js',
                            'lib/**/*'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            debug: {
                tasks: [
                    'nodemon',
                    'node-inspector'
                ],
                options: {
                    logConcurrentOutput: true
                }
            },
            dist: [
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin',
                'htmlmin'
            ]
        },

        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //   dist: {}
        // },

        // Test settings
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true
            }
        },

        mochaTest: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec'
            },
            src: ['test/server/**/*.js']
        },

        env: {
            test: {
                NODE_ENV: 'test'
            }
        }
    });

    // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
    grunt.registerTask('wait', function () {
        grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

        var done = this.async();

        setTimeout(function () {
            grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
            done();
        }, 500);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('express-keepalive', 'Keep grunt running', function () {
        this.async();
    });

    grunt.registerTask('debug', function (target) {
        debugger;
    });
    
    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'express:prod', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
        }

        if (target === 'debug') {
            return grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'bowerInstall',
                'concurrent:server',
                'autoprefixer',
                'concurrent:debug'
            ]);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'bowerInstall',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'express:dev',
            'open',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
        if (target === 'server') {
            return grunt.task.run([
                'env:test',
                'mochaTest'
            ]);
        }

        else if (target === 'client') {
            return grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'concurrent:test',
                'autoprefixer',
                'karma'
            ]);
        }

        else grunt.task.run([
                'test:server',
                'test:client'
            ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'bowerInstall',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'ngmin',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('heroku', function () {
        grunt.log.warn('The `heroku` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt build` to build for deployment.');
        grunt.task.run(['build']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can set node to run a process in debug mode (with a port) by specifying it on the command line: `node --debug=5959 app.js`.  Though you have a large grunt file which you might want this option integrated within?

Comment: I've found out that Protractor's debug port was hardcoded, I've filled out an issue on their github page and it was resolved in several hours.

Comment: how did you finally manage it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with grunt-express-server, rather than protractor, and upon investigation it turns out that the port isn't being picked up by grunt-express-server.

I made the change locally and have also have forked the grunt-express-server repo. There is a pull request that I just created here:

https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server/pull/84

you can apply the same change in your local grunt-express-server code base and then you can set the port from the grunt.js config like this:

```
express: {
      options: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 9000
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: 'server/app.js',
          debug: 5859
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          script: 'dist/server/app.js'
        }
      }
    },
```

note the debug port there.